# Mazes For Two or More

Tags: puzzle-creation, mazes

I am interested in mazes that can be adapted to require two or more people to cooperate to solve. Some examples include Robert Abbott's Meteor Storm and [Valentine's Day](http://logicmazes.com/covers/val.html), as well as Oskar van Deventer's Counter-Step Maze and his three dimensional mazes broken into three planes. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Nice question, but I don't know if this would be considered “subjective”.  You should probably add some more criteria for the type of maze you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Great set of ideas. I enjoyed the Valentine's puzzle link. Many of Oscar's puzzles are implemented on Andrea Gilbert's website [clickmazes.com](http://clickmazes.com).

The example that springs to mind is the (excellent) [Hanayama Labrinth](http://a.co/2pudgQi). I guess similar conceptually to the three dimensional maze projected on three faces, but with only two faces, so the pair analogy is easier to see.